# how to pass data to previous viewController in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

My question is duplicate but I need not a suitable answer. Also, I have raised the same before [how to callback the array of data to another viewController in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474304/how-to-callback-the-array-of-data-to-another-viewcontroller-in-ios-swift)

I have a parent viewController called CreateCardViewController and a child controller called webViewController.

In parent viewController, I have used carbonKit for showing the tab bar menu. When the tab bar menu first index is webViewController (that's a child controller).

My question is: How to send data to the parent controller from the child controller?

For example: From a child, viewController will get a list of tab bar menu items. After getting tab bar menu items, I need to send menu items to parent viewController to show tab bar.

Here is the clear picture, which I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use delegate like what @Aqua said. or use observation for this.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateParentViewController(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "updateParentViewController"), object: nil) 
 }
@IBaction func updateParentViewController(_ notification: NSNotification){
if let receivedData = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? Any {
    //use received data 
    // update your parentViewController. 
}
}
}

//.............

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
func sendDataToParentViewController() {
        let dataDict:[String: Any] = ["data"://what you want to send.]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: . updateParentViewController, object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }
}
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On your custom ChildViewController add property`parentViewController` and set it when you create that child view controller. Then, implement specific method on parent viewcontroller, that receives data from child view controller.

```
protocol ParentViewControllerProtocol {
    func receiveChildData(_ child: UIViewController, data: Any)
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var parentViewController: ParentViewControllerProtocol!

    func timeToSendDataToParentViewController() {
         parentViewController.receiveChildData(self, data: self.data)
    }
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController, ParentViewControllerProtocol {
     func receiveChildData(_ child: UIViewController, data: Any) {/*handle data*/}

     func addChildViewController() {
        let child = ChildViewController();
        child.parentViewController = self
        // do the rest of adding child to parent
     }
}
```

Comment: it shows error Property 'parentViewController' with type 'ParentViewControllerProtocol?' cannot override a property with type 'UIViewController?'